# Call Directory Extension - Error Enabling Extension. Failed to request data

Tags: ios, iphone

Our app is using the caller id feature of Call Directory Extension. It seems to work well for most users. However one user is reporting that he cannot enable the extension in Settings > Phone > Call Blocking & Identification. He gets the message "Error Enabling Extension. Failed to request data for appName. You may try enabling the extension again..." So far I have not been able to replicate this. Has any one else seen this? What was your solution?

Comment: Any update in this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue and as Jimi said there were no duplicate numbers. After debugging and testing I came to know that it requires the array in **ascending order**. I then **sorted my array of phone numbers** and it started working again.

Hope this help someone who is still struggling!

Comment: This was the problem I was having. Data was not sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Well I had a similar case with a user that was trying to enable the extension from Settings -> Phone -> Call Blocking & Identification and was getting the same message as above.

What I found out, after debugging requests to our company's catalog, was that I had **one or more duplicate entries such as [12345, John Doe], [12345, Jane Doe]**.

That **didn't cause any trouble to users that already had the extension enabled on their devices** (at least I had no complaints whatsoever), but made the extension impossible to enable for users that didn't have enable the extension before.

Now, I can not guarantee this is the case for your problem, but you can start by checking for duplicate entries in Directory.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was calling `context.removeAllIdentificationEntries()` when `context.isIncremental` was `false`. When I connected the debugger to the extension and tried enabling my app for Call Blocking & Identification, I saw the exception:

`Exception: Calling removeAllIdentificationEntries when isIncremental is false is unsupported`

Removing `context.removeAllIdentificationEntries()` fixed the failing enablement problem for me.